# Android MonthDisplayHelper doesn't provide the days in the proper order

Tags: android, date, calendar

I am trying to make a custom Calendar view and for that I use [MonthDisplayHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/MonthDisplayHelper.html) to get the days of the month and a `GridView` to display them.

The problem is that `MonthDisplayHelper` is not giving me the right days order, for example if the current date is 02.20.2012, the `MonthDisplayHelper` gives me the following days in this order:

Sun --- Mon --- Tue --- Wed --- Thu --- Fri --- Sat

31 --------1 ------ 2 ------ 3------- 4 ------ 5 ------ 6

7 ------  8  ------ 9 ------ 10 ------ 11 ------ 12 ---- 13

14 ----- 15 ----- 16 -----17 ----- 18 ----- 19 ----- 20 -- <= the current day here is Sat but in reality is Mon

21 ----- 22 ----- 23 ----- 24 ----- 25 ----- 26 ----- 27

28 ------ 29 ------1 ------ 2  ------ 3 ------ 4 ------ 5

So the previous month days should start from 29(on Sunday) and end with the next month days (3 on Sat)

I get the days from the `MonthDisplayHelper` like this:

```
calendarHelper = new MonthDisplayHelper(2012, 1, Calendar.SUNDAY);
int thisDay = calendarHelper.getDayAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

and I am incrementing the rowIndex and columnIndex each time the `getView()` is called like this:

```
if (columnIndex >= 7) {
            rowIndex++;
            columnIndex = -1;
        }

columnIndex += 1;
```

Comment: There are a few calendar libraries (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8242625/119895). I would check how they are handling this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I made more debugs and noticed that MonthDisplayHelper does give me the correct days but I think my gridView adapter is the problem now..

Comment: It seems that my Adapter getView() method gives me 2 or 3 times at the start only value 0 for the index I get from it and I am making the increments anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was the gridview adapter, when it runs it gives me the same index for two or three time in a row and only after that the index gets incremented..
I modified the increment method to do the incrementation of column and row index only if the grid index is not the same as the last given one..

I'm still wondering why the adapter is doing this strange thing.. maybe someone could tell why..

Thanks