# opening default calendar application from another app in android

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to open default calendar application from my application in android. I did get some links in regard to this

```
  Intent calendarIntent = new Intent() ;
  calendarIntent.putExtra("beginTime", tempCal.getTimeInMillis());
  calendarIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | 
                      Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  calendarIntent.setClassName("com.android.calendar","com.android.calendar.AgendaActivity");
            startActivity(calendarIntent);
```

This does open the calendar. But, I want the calendar app to open in the month mode (showing list of days in month). I need help on this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reviewing the Calendar App in the Android source code you can only invoke the AgendaActivity directly. The others will not work. You can interact directly with the cursor to read/create events, but you can't invoke the calendar app to a view other than the AgendaView. The reason is that the developers have limited that ability in the manifest for the Cal app by using the following activity definitions:

```
 <activity android:name="MonthActivity" android:label="@string/month_view"
        android:theme="@style/CalendarTheme" />
    <activity android:name="WeekActivity" android:label="@string/week_view"
        android:theme="@style/CalendarTheme" />
    <activity android:label="@string/day_view" android:name="DayActivity"     
        android:theme="@style/CalendarTheme"/>
    <activity android:name="AgendaActivity" android:label="@string/agenda_view"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Note that only the AgendaActivity has `android:exported="true"`. If you attempt to call the other activities you will get a permission exception.

Comment: for more on this, try reading the [launcher activity source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/blob/master/src/com/android/calendar/AllInOneActivity.java) for the calendar app

Comment: just a helpful addon if u need calendar kind of view. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8242625/539472)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be using the Calendar Intents which are defined by the `Calendar Provider`. This will make it more future proof, as hard coding the class of the activity that you want to start is not such a good idea. Besides that it can vary between devices.

The full documentation of those can be found [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents).

Unfotunately these don't seem to allow to set a specific viewing mode when you use `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` to just view the calendar.