# Can we get native calendar view in android api 8?

Tags: android, calendar

i have seen lots of blogs and post here for get calendar view in api 8 through customize it in grid view and all but can it possible to get native calendar view in lower api by support library or through any idea??  i know it is not directly get calendar view below api level 11

Comment: This question has been asked before and is also answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241674/calendar-view-for-android-api-11

Comment: @TIM this question hasn't ever asked. thanks for answer but i think you not read it seriously .. i mention here through using support library can we use calendar in api 8??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CalendarView` is not in the Android Support library. You can tell that by reading the Android JavaDocs and noticing that there is only [one `CalendarView` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), the one that was added in API Level 11.

There is [a third-party backport](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/ics-calendarview/), in addition to the answers outlined in [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241674/calendar-view-for-android-api-11).