# Default android calendar view for android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, android-widget

I googled lot about calendar view in android, but could not find the better way to implement android calendar view for API level 8.

the default `calenderview` is supported on or after API level 11, but how can i get the same view working for API level 8?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8242625/2649012

Comment: i saw that, any simple and best example which u suggest

Comment: The first one looks great

Answer (score 0):

You can use [android-calendarview](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview) which contains CalendarView from v4.0 backported to v2.2